# Excel VBA Overflow error when trying to run SQL server stored proc with Int parameter

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I have an OrderID of 32777 declared as **Long** data type in excel. Im trying to pass it to a stored procedure with the following line of code:

```
RunStoredProcedure "dbo.updateinventory", CLng(OrderID), "Orderid"
```

I get the following error when i try,despite including the CLng function.The line highlighted by the debugger is the one above:

[image]

The original stored procedure is shown below.

```
@OrderId Int
as
Begin
   update P
Set
    P.Available = P.Available - Q.QuantityOrdered,
From
Products P  join
(Select ProductID, sum(Quantity) from OrderDetails where OrderID = @OrderId Group By ProductId)  Q
on P.ID = Q.ProductID

End
```

I have tried changing the data type of the @Orderid variable to a BigInt on the stored procedure but still get the error.

**EDIT:** I have changed the data type of the OrderID column in the orderdetails table from int to bigint, but still get the error.

Can anyone assist please?

cheers

Comment: If the error occurs, click [Debug]. The Code will be displayed and the erroneous code line yellow highlighted. Now hover the mouse pointer over `OrderID` in that line. What is displayed as the value of  `OrderID` then?

Comment: its 32777. cheers

Comment: I'd assume, that this error is not coming from the parameter, but somewhere from inside your SP. If the code you posted is your original code, there's something wrong here: Your `sum(Quantity)` hasn't got an alias, but you seem to refer to this as `Q.QuatityOrdered`.

Comment: Then the second parameter in your `Sub`or `Function` `RunStoredProcedure "dbo.updateinventory", CLng(OrderID), "Orderid"` does not expect a `Long` but a `Integer`. Please show your  `Sub`or `Function` `RunStoredProcedure(...`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem! It's within the VBA code BEFORE the data hits the database. The value is cast back to an int! Doh

Thanks all for your replies !